# Impresora en java

Tags: java, impresora

ok tengo una duda muy puntual

quiero imprimir una imagen desde un código java:

1- sin botones de confirmación

2-sin que se cambie el tamaño de la imagen

1-el primer punto creo que lo logre pero no se si es la forma mas correcta ya que cambia el tamaño de la imagen y la posición inicial

2-no se como hacerlo,necesito ayuda

```
public static void main(String[] args){
try { 
    Impresora.listarImpresoras();
    impresora.imprimirDirecto
    ("C:\\Users\\CRISTIAN\\Documents\\folders\\documentos\\2.png",3);
                        //3 representa la impresora en un arreglo 
   }catch (Exception ex) {

                         }
}


public static void imprimirDirecto(String cadena,int i) {
try {
PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
                         pras.add(new Copies(1));

                         PrintService ps;
                                       ps = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null)[i];
                         DocPrintJob docPrintJob = ps.createPrintJob();
                         DocFlavor docFormat = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PNG;
         FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(cadena);

         Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(fileInputStream, docFormat,  null);

        docPrintJob.print(doc, pras);
} catch (Exception e) {

                      }
}


public static String[] listarImpresoras() {

                    PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
                    String impresoras[]=new String[printServices.length];
                    System.out.println("Lista de impresoras disponibles");
            int i=0;
                    for (PrintService printService: printServices) {
                        impresoras[i]=printService.getName();
                            System.out.println("\t" + printService.getName());
                            i++;
                    }
                    return impresoras;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya lo pude resolver el problema aquí les comparto

```
public static void imprimirDirecto(String url, int i) {
         FileInputStream archivo; 
        try { 
         archivo =new FileInputStream(url);  
         DocFlavor formato = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PNG; 
         Doc documento = new SimpleDoc(archivo, formato, null);  
         PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();

        //----las opciones que me interesan configurar de la impresora
        aset.add(MediaSizeName.NA_LETTER);//el tamaño de la hoja (carta)
       // aset.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);
        aset.add(new Copies(1));
        //aset.add(Chromaticity.MONOCHROME);
       // aset.add(OrientationRequested.PORTRAIT); 
        // discover the printers that can print the format according to the
        // instructions in the attribute set
        PrintService[] services =
                PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(formato, aset);
        // Create a print job from one of the print services
        if (services.length > 0) { 
                DocPrintJob job = services[i].createPrintJob(); 
                try { 
                        job.print(documento, aset); 
                } catch (PrintException pe) {} 
        } 
        }catch(Exception e){

        }  
    }
```